# Computation of a sum $S(n)$

Tags: real-analysis

We have the following sum:

$ \forall \; n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0, 1 \} $ we define:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
S(n) & = (1 \times 2) + (1 \times 3) + \dots + (1 \times n) \\
 & + (2\times3) + (2 \times 4) + \dots + (2 \times n)  \\
 & + ... \\
 & + (n - 2) \times (n- 1) + (n - 2) \times n \\
 & + (n - 1) \times n 
\end{split} 
\end{equation*}

What I've done so far?

Well, I consider only the first line and obtain $\dfrac{1}{2}$ $(n^2 + n - 2)$, considering the second line I get $(n^2 + n - 6)$. The sums of the last two lines are $(n-2)(2n-1)$ and $n(n-1)$.

So far, so good. But I don't see how to calculate the whole sum. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: distributivity.

$$\begin{align}S(n) &= 1 \times (2 + 3 + 4 + \ldots + n)\\
&+2 \times ( 3 + 4 + \ldots + n)\\
&+ \ldots\\
&+ (n-2) \times (n-1 + n)\\
&+ (n-1) \times n\\
\end{align}$$

And then it should be pretty straight-forward, when you recall how to take a sum of the form $2+3+ \ldots + n$.

Answer (score 1):

After using distributivity I get:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
S(n) & = 1 \times (2 + 3 + 4 + \dots + n) \\
 & + 2 \times (3 + 4 + 5 + \dots + n)  \\
 & + 3 \times (4 + 5 + 6 + \dots + n) \\
 & + 4 \times (5 + 6 + 7 + \dots + n) \\
 & + \dots
\end{split} 
\end{equation*}

I can rewrite this as:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
S(n) & = \dfrac{1}{2} \ (n^2 + n - 2) & = \dfrac{1}{2} \ (n+2)(n-1)  \\
 & + \dfrac{2}{2} \ (n^2 + n - 6) & = \dfrac{2}{2} \ (n+3)(n-2)  \\
 & + \dfrac{3}{2} \ (n^2 + n - 12) & = \dfrac{3}{2} \ (n+4)(n-3)    \\
 & + \dfrac{4}{2} \ (n^2 + n - 20) & = \dfrac{4}{2} \ (n+5)(n-4)  \\
 & + \dots
\end{split} 
\end{equation*}

Is this right so far? I still don't see how to get the formula for the sum $S(n)$

Comment: That's right so far. Now notice that you can multiply the entire thing by two to get rid of the fraction at the very start. Then notice that after that, certain terms that look quite similar. What can you do about $(n+x)$ and $(n-x)$?